# why std::async not really works and is not asynchronous

Tags: c++, multithreading, libvlc

i want write simple program have two threads one print numbers in console and other play mp3 with libVLC as asynchronous parallel threads. but when run my code first print 1 then play mp3 and when mp3 end now print next number?
my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <future>
void alarmStart()
{
    if (!IsthreadActive)
    {
        IsthreadActive = true;
        auto handle = std::async(playAlarm);

    }
}
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0;; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " \n";
        alarmStart();
    }
    return 0;
}



void playAlarm()
{
    libvlc_instance_t *inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;
    // load the vlc engine
    inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    // create a new item
    m = libvlc_media_new_path(inst, "alarm.mp3");
    // create a media play playing environment
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
    // no need to keep the media now
    libvlc_media_release(m);
    // play the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);
    Sleep(3000);
    // stop playing
    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);
    // free the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
    libvlc_release(inst);
    IsthreadActive = false;
}
```

i test std::thread but without join rise this exception :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x773891CB (ucrtbase.dll)
```

and with join is the same as async.
how can i run two parallel thread in c++?